# Use of new DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Why this doesn't work :

```
$start = new DateTime('2018-03-11 22:05:43');
$end = new DateTime('2018-03-11 23:15:23');
$interval = $end->diff($start);
echo $interval;
```

I want to get the difference between two dates and I think it better to use `DateTime` than `strtotime`.

Thanks.

Comment: please explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: its just a DateTime object, to get some meaning out of it, you'll have to use the appropriate method, `->format('date format here')` or whatever, just read the php docs